# UIButton's image doesn't update after status change

Tags: cocoa, uiimage, uibutton, selected

I've created UIButton and set its images this way:

```
  [_filterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_filterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Later on I change its status: (I do it after clicking different button)

```
[_filterButton setSelected:YES];
```

However, button's image doesn't update until I click it.

It seems that button's image is updated after touch event and not after changing it status manually.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was updating button status not in a main thread and this was causing problems.